# I am getting "No rows at position 0" while I try to retrieve a value from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am getting an error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: No rows at position 0.

From this line:

```
string value = dt.Rows[0]["Project"].ToString();
```

Full event:

```
protected void RadDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
{
    RadDropDownList droplist = sender as RadDropDownList;
    GridDataItem item = droplist.NamingContainer as GridDataItem;
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable("SELECT Project FROM Pnum WHERE Project='"+ droplist.SelectedItem.Text +"'");
    string value = dt.Rows[0]["Project"].ToString();
    item["Project"].Text = value;
}

public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WTAConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    return dt;
}
```

I did some debugging, the value of `droplist.SelectedItem.Text` is correct and I checked the values in the table and there are values available. What should I look for?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You must close connection before exiting from method `GetDataTable`.

Comment: @mason Thanks, your hint helped me to sort out the problem. Please post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be rows if the query returned any results. Verify that your query returns results by running the query directly against the database. Use the Visual Studio debugging tools to get the query (don't just type it) because the query may not be as you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you Mason. The problem was the query as per your assuption.

Answer (score 1):

It means your query returned no results.  Put a breakpoint in on this line:

```
string value = dt.Rows[0]["Project"].ToString();
```

and in the debugger, use the DataTable Visualizer to look at the value of `dt`.  It'll be empty.

Check what value you are getting from `droplist.SelectedItem.Text`, it probably isn't what you're wanting.  Also, you should use SQL parameters to avoid injection.

Answer (score 1):

Check that whether datatable have any rows or not.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable("SELECT Project FROM Pnum WHERE Project='"+ droplist.SelectedItem.Text +"'");

if(dt!=null && dt.Rows.Count>0)
{    
string value = dt.Rows[0]["Project"].ToString();
item["Project"].Text = value;
}
```